# Percentile excluding 0 in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Is there a way to ignore `0` in **Google Sheets** when using:

```
=Percentile(A:A,0.9)
```

Like in **Excel**:

```
=PERCENTILE(IF(A1:A18,A1:A18),0.3)
```

But that doesn't seem to work in Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query formula to exclude 0's

```
=PERCENTILE(QUERY(A:A,"where A<>0"), 0.9)
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)